# I get bad request when I send a POST request to create a new user

Tags: python, serialization, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm trying to test registering new users, I send a POST request and I get "details": "USER WITH THIS EMAIL ALREADY EXITS!", even though when i check in the database the new user does get created.. I delete it and try again, still get the same outcome.. Having a hard time finding what's wrong with my code

views.py:

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):

    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(self.user).data
        for k,v in serializer.items():
            data[k]=v

        return data

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer


@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getUserProfile(request):
    user = request.user
    serializer = UserSerializer(user,many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAdminUser])
def getUsers(request):
    user = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(user,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

# Register new users
@api_view(['POST'])
def registerUser(request):
    data = request.data
    print(data)
    try:
        user = User.objects.create(
            first_name = data['name'],
            username = data['email'],
            email = data['email'],
            password = make_password(data['password']),
        )
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    except:
        message = {'details': 'USER WITH THIS EMAIL ALREADY EXITS!'}
        return Response(message, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    _id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin']

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.first_name
        if name == "":
            name = obj.email
        return name

    def get__id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff

class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', '_id', 'username', 'email', 'name', 'isAdmin', 'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from app import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import (
    TokenObtainPairView,
)

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.getRoutes, name="get-routes"),
path('users/register/', views.registerUser, name="register"),
path('users/login/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('products/', views.getProducts, name="get-products"),
path('products/<str:pk>', views.getProduct, name="get-product"),
path('user/profile/', views.getUserProfile, name="get-user-profile"),
path('users/', views.getUsers, name="get-users"),
]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    brand=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    rating=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    numReviews=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    countInStock=models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user gets created, the problem is in the next lines. Remove the "try" and you'll probably see an exception in `serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(user, many=False)` or in `return Response(serializer.data)`. You are currently catching **all** exceptions, and sending your message ("USER WITH THIS EMAIL ALREADY EXITS!"), even though that may not be the problem. You should avoid using a simple "except" and instead catch the specific exception you need to catch.

Comment: When I did that I got "500Internal Server Error", "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `_id` is not valid for model `User`." @jfchuman

Comment: Try renaming your field without the leading underscore, I think Django has some problems with it.

Comment: That error is gone but still get  "500Internal Server Error @jfchuman

Comment: Then "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `name` is not valid for model `User`." @jfchuman

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).